# VB.net/Word Addin: URL encoding

Tags: vb.net, url, urlencode, word-addins

I'm creating an addin in Word 2013 with vb.net.
I have trouble for encoding a URL. I've seen from other questions that we can use HttpUtility.UrlEncode(string) to encode it, but when I do this, it's not encoded the way I would like it to be. For example "the department's activities" should be encoded as "the+department%27s+activities", but instead I have "the+department%E2%80%99s+activities".

Any idea how I could achieve the result I need? Thanks!

Comment: WebUtility.UrlEncode()

Comment: @Jimi thanks for your help. I've tried this one too, but it's the same unfortunately

Comment: Of course I have tested it. I mean, I've tested the string you passed in your question.

Comment: If you Decode it -> `WebUtility.UrlDecode()` you will see that the string you are trying to encode does not contain (') -> chr(39) but (’). Usually a MS Word quotation mark. [Wikipedia - Quotation mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotation_mark). It's the second **quotation mark** in the table you see on the right.

Comment: omg... That totally make sense ! It didn't cross my mind... Thankl you so much. I feel terrible lol

Comment: Don't. BTW, it's Unicode value is U+2019.